# get cell value from a dynamic HTML table according to the contents of the first line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in html that its order of columns can change. The code of this table is:

```
<table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Place</td>
            <td>Population</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Phoenix city</td>
            <td>1445632</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>San Antonio city</td>
            <td>1327407</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>San Diego city</td>
            <td>1307402</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Dallas city</td>
            <td>1197816</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>San Jose city</td>
            <td>945942</td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the value that has the id equal to 2 column that has the first line says "Place". The jquery code I'm using to try to do this it is:

```
//Convert Object
    var table = $('#table');
    //get cell
    var valuefinal = $(table).find("tr").eq(2).find("td").text("Place");
    //display value
    alert(valuefinal);
```

Is it possible to do this? I believe it is very complex to do this

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/SdBBy/311/)

Comment: *I need to get the value that has the id equal to 2 column that has the first line says "Place"*. Can you explain that clearly?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do, please clearify!

Comment: Friends will better explain what I want. The columns of the table can change my order. Knowing this I need to search a column that has its first line the word "place". This is the line that has your ID (first column) equal to 2. http://i.imgur.com/xJagBAa.jpg Gotta understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4w7Z/)

Looks like you're looking for a more dynamic solution.  See demo above and code below:

```
    var table = $('#table'),
        colHeader = {};
    table.find('tr').eq(0).children('td')
    .each(function(i,v) { 
        colHeader[ $(v).text() ] = i;
    });
    console.log( colHeader );
    var valuefinal = table.find('tr').filter(function(){
        return $(this).children('td').eq( colHeader['ID'] ).text() == 2;
    })
    .children('td').eq( colHeader['Place'] ).text();
    alert(valuefinal);
```

Comment: But my table is dynamic and can change order, then he would need to get the word "place" in the first line of my table.

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you saying the order of your columns(not rows) will change?

Comment: The columns of the table can change my order. Knowing this I need to search a column that has its first line the word "place". This is the line that has your ID (first column) equal to 2. i.imgur.com/xJagBAa.jpg Gotta understand now?

Comment: INCREDIBLE!! YOU AMAZING! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will select the TD you are looking for if that is what you mean.

```
var cell = $("td:contains('Place')");
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

**Edit: After your comment:**

I think this is what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/SdBBy/316/

> //get cell      var valuefinal =
>   $(table).find("td:nth-child(2)").eq(2).text();

Comment: But with this I'll be able to get the content that is in the same column as the "Place" column that is the line that has your ID equal to 2? http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/SdBBy/311/

Comment: But my table is dynamic and can change order, then he would need to get the word "place" in the first line of my table.

Comment: I think you have enough to get started. You could have put some of this information in your question.

Comment: **CAREFULLY** read the first part of my question "I have a table in html that its order of columns can change....."